# Why my database get the same userid?

Tags: php

I just want to know why my databases keep getting the same userid 
even I logged in with different user.

[image: here is my users table]

[image: here is my cart info...]

cartID 54 is 'reinhart' user
cartID 55 is 'caspe' user

but they have the same userid in cart table.

It happened when I tried to insert new data entries from productinfo.php

here is my code

productinfouser.php

```
<?php @session_start(); ?>
<?php require_once('Connections/localhost.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "productform.php")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO cart (name, brand, category, price, userid) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['brand'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['category'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['price'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['userid_hiddenfield'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "shoppingcart.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "")
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "")
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$query_productinfo = "SELECT * FROM firstci_ecommercedb.product";
$productinfo = mysql_query($query_productinfo, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
$row_productinfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($productinfo);
$totalRows_productinfo = mysql_num_rows($productinfo);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM users";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>productinfo</title>
<link href="css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/productinfostyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header"></div>
     <!-- *************************** MENU -->
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Order</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- *************************** CATEGORY -->
    <div id="category"><ul>
            <li><a href="computers.php"><img src="images/menudesktop.png" width="333" height="100" border="0"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="laptops.php"><img src="images/menulaptop.png" width="333" height="100" alt=""/></a></li>
            <li><a href="mobiles.php"><img src="images/menumobile.png" width="333" height="100" alt=""/></a></li>
        </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- *************************** BRAND -->
    <div id="brand">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Intel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lenovo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Samsung</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dell</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cherry Mobile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

  <!-- *************************** MAINBODY -->
    <div id="mainbody">
        <form id="productform" name="productform.php" method="POST" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
          <div id="itemimg"><img src="images/cart.png" /></div>
            <div id="itemdesc"><br />
              <br />
              <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td width="301"><table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>
                      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>" name="name" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $_POST['brand']; ?>
                      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['brand']; ?>" name="brand" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $_POST['category']; ?>
                      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['category']; ?>" name="category" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $_POST['price']; ?>
                      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['price']; ?>" name="price" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
                      <input name="userid_hiddenfield" type="hidden" id="userid_hiddenfield" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['userid']; ?>" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><input name="hfname" type="hidden" id="hfname" value="<?php echo $row_productinfo['name']; ?>" />
                      <input name="brandhf" type="hidden" id="brandhf" value="<?php echo $row_productinfo['brand']; ?>" />
                      <input name="cateagoryhf" type="hidden" id="cateagoryhf" value="<?php echo $row_productinfo['category']; ?>" />
                      <input name="pricehf" type="hidden" id="pricehf" value="<?php echo $row_productinfo['price']; ?>" />
                      <input name="descriptionhf" type="hidden" id="descriptionhf" value="<?php echo $row_productinfo['description']; ?>" /></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
                  <td width="299"><?php echo $_POST['description']; ?>
                  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['description']; ?>" name="description" /></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="productform.php" />
        </form>
  </div>
  <!-- *************************** FOOTER -->
    <div id="footer"><p>Runts & Giants</p></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($productinfo);

mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
?>
```

Here is my product table structure

[image]

Comment: your query is `SELECT * FROM users` without where how can you achieve and differ userid?

Comment: use a `where clause` or a loop like `while loop` in your query, looping will give you multiple records

Comment: That's also my problem...

Comment: um.. sir, why am i getting the same userid?

Comment: you need to fetch login userid from session or cookie and match with your query like `select * from users where user_id = "$getUserId"`. Something like this.

Comment: sir. do I have to do some changes with my codes?

Comment: can you please show your product table structure?

Comment: Ok sir.. but my only problem is my cart table get the same userid with different users (see the two images above) do you still want me to show my product table?

Comment: Actually problem is you are fetching first userid always as you not use `WHERE` condition so how can you get different userid? You need to use any condtion to differ and get proper userid.

Comment: done with the attachment sir..

Comment: how can I set a condition sir ?

Comment: are you not getting me. I am telling you that you need some common value in product and user table if its not exist then you need to check for WHERE condition to fetch userId. If you use `select * from users` it will give you always one same row.

Comment: have you got any solution?

Comment: "select * from users where userid = '%s'"

Comment: is it something like that ?